# QNAP NAS TS-431P2 cannot connect via VScode ssh

Tags: vscode-remote-ssh

I need the functionality to be be able to connect to my QNAP NAS from win10 via ssh using VScode Remote-ssh.
In the process of running the ssh from VScode it seems that some command are not recognized by the

```
`NAS so the ssh connection is not established:
[09:31:39.387] Showing password prompt
[09:31:45.939] Got password response
[09:31:45.939] "install" wrote data to terminal: "***********"
[09:31:45.953] >
[09:31:46.059] > 3a63c10769b3: running
[09:31:46.076] > grep: invalid option -- 'a'

BusyBox v1.01 (2023.04.20-19:11+0000) multi-call binary

Usage: grep [-ihHnqvs] PATTERN [FILEs...]

Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.

Options:
-H prefix output lines with filename where match was found
-h suppress the prefixing filename on output
-i ignore case distinctions
-l list names of files that match
-n print line number with output lines
-q be quiet. Returns 0 if result was found, 1 otherwise
-v select non-matching lines
-s suppress file open/read error messages

grep: invalid option -- 'a'
BusyBox v1.01 (2023.04.20-19:11+0000) multi-call binary`
```

This is the only message that I get looking on output and the:
Setting up SSH Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: (details) Initializing VS Code ServerAll the credentials are correct
is never performed.

Does anyone had this issue? Is there a solution for this? Thank you.

uninstall and install again Remote-ssh
double check the config file for remote-ssh
Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host...